# EEPROM usage in ZS-042

Tags: pcb, clock, eeprom

I have bought a realtime clock module ([this](https://www.gmelectronic.com/modul-rtc-ds323-i2c-and-32kb-flash) one). According to the sparse data I found there is a EEPROM on it. It's called 24C32 as can be seen on this schematic I found:

[image]

As I want to rebuild this schematic as a part of a custom PCB I wonder what this EEPROM is used for? What would be the implications if I just don't include it?

Comment: Please refer to DS3231 datasheet for example schematics. This module is very suspicious, as lithium coin cells are not reachargeable and they should never be fed with current at all, yet the circuit is designed to provide current to the 2032 coin cell.

Comment: In this datasheet: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/112132/DALLAS/DS3231.html there is a example schematic. However some values like RPU are missing. But combinde with the example from my initial question this should be suffucient (hopefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EEPROM has nothing to do with the RTC functionality directly and can be removed. However, it can be used for logging data that is time-dependent which is pretty handy.